# wpf background worker not displaying data from the method

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        loadtest();
    }

    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Progress Bar Window close

        pop.Close();

    }

    private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pop.prgTest.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }


    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Background Worker code///
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

        //Progress Bar Window
        pop.Show();
    }
```

The load test here is...a method that picks up few images from database and displays them. The method works fine if the run the method on page initialisation but its not giving any output when i load them like this in background worker.....here is the method loadtest.

```
public void loadtest()
    {

        string query = "select*from question where id='" + 1 + "'";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string qid = myReader.GetInt32("id").ToString();

                byte[] imgg1q1 = (byte[])(myReader["question"]);
                byte[] imgg2q1 = (byte[])(myReader["opt1"]);
                byte[] imgg3q1 = (byte[])(myReader["opt2"]);
                byte[] imgg4q1 = (byte[])(myReader["opt3"]);
                byte[] imgg5q1 = (byte[])(myReader["opt4"]);


                MemoryStream mstreamq1 = new MemoryStream(imgg1q1);
                MemoryStream mstream1q1 = new MemoryStream(imgg2q1);
                MemoryStream mstream2q1 = new MemoryStream(imgg3q1);
                MemoryStream mstream3q1 = new MemoryStream(imgg4q1);
                MemoryStream mstream4q1 = new MemoryStream(imgg5q1);


                q1.BeginInit();
                q1.StreamSource = mstreamq1;
                q1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                q1.EndInit();

                // Assign the Source property of your image
                q_image.Source = q1;


                q1opt1.BeginInit();
                q1opt1.StreamSource = mstream1q1;
                q1opt1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                q1opt1.EndInit();

                option_1.Source = q1opt1;


                q1opt2.BeginInit();
                q1opt2.StreamSource = mstream2q1;
                q1opt2.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                q1opt2.EndInit();

                option_2.Source = q1opt2;


                q1opt3.BeginInit();
                q1opt3.StreamSource = mstream3q1;
                q1opt3.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                q1opt3.EndInit();
                option_3.Source = q1opt3;


                q1opt4.BeginInit();
                q1opt4.StreamSource = mstream4q1;
                q1opt4.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                q1opt4.EndInit();

                option_4.Source = q1opt4;


            }


            conDataBase.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }



    }
```

i am using a background worker to display a popup of loading progressbar until the page loads and popup is a function that will display a new popup window which says loading....
the loadtest method works properly everywhere but its not working with the backgroundworker...the funtion loadtest picks some images from database which takes time and i am displaying a popup until the images are getting loaded and  the dispalying in  option_2.source,option_2.source,option_3.source and option_4.source..........

Comment: Aside from your background issue, take a look at your query, and I am sure it is just a sample... You have a hard value of 1, but if coming from outside source, be sure to parameterize the query otherwise you are open for sql-injection.

Comment: If you are just starting the project, you may consider using `Task`s rather than `Backgroundworker` as they are easier to implement in WPF and MVVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change control properties directly from a background thread. Instead send them over to the UI thread in order to use them. One way to do this would be via [`BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method (Int32, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx) see also [Updating UI with BackgroundWorker in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16739039/5265292)

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    loadtest(sender as BackgroundWorker);
}
```

and

```
public void loadtest(BackgroundWorker bw)
{
    //... your code

    q1.BeginInit();
    q1.StreamSource = mstreamq1;
    q1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    q1.EndInit();
    // by freezing the image, it will become available to the UI thread
    q1.Freeze();

    // Don't directly assign the Source property of your image
    // q_image.Source = q1;
    // Instead, report progress to the UI thread:
    bw.ReportProgress.ReportProgress(25, new Tuple<Image, ImageSource>(q_image, q1));

    //... your code
}

private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pop.prgTest.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

    // assign the image source on the UI thread
    var data = e.UserState as Tuple<Image, ImageSource>;
    data.Item1.Source = data.Item2;
}
```

**Edit:** added the `Freeze()` call to image after initialization. This is necessary in order to allow access to the image outside the worker thread where it was created.

As a side note: Please replace your empty `catch { }` block with some actual error checking... I suppose you just suppressed the relevant exceptions there that would help in identifying the issues.

Comment: i dont know whats the issue code is running properly but no image is being displayed ..i dont understand the issue...can i contact you your email or something i need help with it

Comment: Stackoverflow is meant to provide public available questions and answers, so no email. However, I will try to create a sample project later to mimic your code as good as I can. Maybe I'm able to reproduce the issue...

Comment: thnq so much for that the project is simple it displays images from the database and shows a loading icon until the images loads and store them in a variable so that i can call them later also............

Comment: when can i expect your project that will be so kind of you.....and where you gonna send that to me...?

Comment: @Saurabh edited my answer. Was missing a `Freeze()` call on the image so the assignment in `ProgressChanged` would work without error.

Comment: i just edited my empty catch with a message box (showing exception error)  ...................... MessageBox.Show("A handled exception just occurred: " + ex.Message, "Exception Sample", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning); ..........      and it gave me the error  "A handled exception just occured the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".......what does this means..?

Answer (score 0):

The backgroundworker has the ReportProgress method with which you can report periodic progress of the background to the UI.

Set the WorkerReportsProgress to true, as this defaults to false.

```
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

Then hook up the Progress report event to your UI updating method, bw_ProgressChanged, which you are already doing.

```
 bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
```

Then call in the ReportProgress method wherever you want to update the UI in the Do_Work method. Get the worker from the sender object and pass into the loadtest method and call like below.

```
 bw.ReportProgress(progressPercentage); // This would be % completed you want to display.
```

This should work.

Comment: i already have done all that,........... Thats not the problem......i am using an isdetminate progress bar the problem is that the method loadtest() is not showing output when i call this method in background worker ........otherwise when i use the method simply without backgroundworker it works fine